# How to map inherited entities in EF code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to map the AdventureWorks 2012 sample database to an EF 6.1.3 code-first data layer, and am stuck at how to map the `Employee` and `Person` entities. Employee should apparently derive from `Person`, with a `Person.PersonType` of `EM`, but I don't know how to map this using `EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>` 'mapping' classes. Knowing this, I could also map `Person` to derive from `BusinessEntity`.

Comment: Employee should derive from Person and you have to give them the same PK (let Employee use the inherited PersonID Key). EF will correctly map them.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines and related posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain how to perform the mapping between the `Employee` and the `Person` tables using Code First approach, you can follow the same procedure to map inheritance between `BusinessEntity`and `Person`.

The inheritance mapping strategy used is TPT (Table Per Type), I've created a simple Console Application, With the AdventureWorks2012 Database installed, I followed the EF DataModel Wizard to generate the code first classes that I will modify to map the inheritance, So here is the resulted code:

The Person class:

```
public  partial class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int BusinessEntityID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string PersonType { get; set; }

    public bool NameStyle { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Suffix { get; set; }

    public int EmailPromotion { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "xml")]
    public string AdditionalContactInfo { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "xml")]
    public string Demographics { get; set; }

}
```

The Employee class:

```
 public partial class Employee: Person
{

    [Required]
    public string NationalIDNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LoginID { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public short? OrganizationLevel { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

    public bool SalariedFlag { get; set; }

    public short VacationHours { get; set; }

    public short SickLeaveHours { get; set; }

    public bool CurrentFlag { get; set; }

    public Guid rowguid { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And Finally the AW Context Class:

```
 public partial class AW : DbContext
{
    public AW()
        : base("name=AWConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {            
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().ToTable("Person.Person");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("HumanResources.Employee");
    }
}
```

A simple test (That works for me ;) ):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(var db= new AW())
        {
            var e = db.Employees.First();
            e.JobTitle = "Web Developper";
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

You can refer to [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) article for more details

Comment: One thing I don't see here is how to tell EF that `PersonType` is a 'differentiator` column. We could simply hard set the value 'EM' in the `Employee` ctor, but I somehow thought there was more to this aspect of the mapping.

Comment: by 'differentiator' you mean the 'descriminator' which is used in the TPH inheritance strategy. I haven't specified a discriminator above because I used TPT to map inheretance.

Comment: Yes, that is the term I was looking for. So I suppose here we can merely use the ctor of `Employee` to set that.

Comment: Yeah this may work for the `Employee` class, but checking the values that the `PersonType`column takes (EM,SC,VC,IN, ..etc), from that I don't think there is a corresponding table/class for each value (EM=>Employee, VC=>??). So I think this column has nothing to do with inheretance mapping!